# Verificar si un array contiene un elemento

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy tratando de saber si un array contiene un cierto elemento, el problema es que si pongo un elemento del array me sale *undefined*

```js
var array=[1,6,7];

function contiene(x){
  if(x>0 && x<array.length){
    var res = array[i].indexOf(x);
  }return res;
}

console.log(contiene(7));
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: ¿ De donde sale la `i` ? `array[i].indexOf( )`

Comment: Se ve que ya me marié con los ciclos for que añadí el [i] jaja disculpa

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo te dieron dos respuestas y la más botada fue la mas antigua y por ende mas soportada por la mayoría de los navegadores pero recomiendo el uso de `includes` por los motivos que puedes encontrar en el vínculo siguiente https://www.codementor.io/adroitcoder/includes-vs-indexof-in-javascript-ivxhatb3y

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creo que, o te falta código o te has mareado usando elementos de una iteración `for` en un `if`.

Si sólo quieres saber si el elemento se encuentra en el `array`, con este código bastará

```
function contiene(arr, x) {
    return arr.indexOf(x) >= 0;
}
```

Devuelve `true` si el elemento esta contenido en el `array` o devolverá `false` en caso contrario.

Puedes conocer más sobre el método `indexOf` [en la documentación que ofrece Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/indexOf).

Comment: No puedo creer que haya mezclado tanto jajaaj te agradezco la ayuda

Answer (score 5):

Ya existe una función nativa que retorna `true` o `false`, `includes()` :

```
var array=[1,6,7];
console.log(array.includes(7));
```

Comment: vale, estudiaré el caso del includes(). Gracias por la sugerencia